# replacing space with %20

Tags: c++, arrays

The following program replaces all spaces with %20.the compilation works fine but the program terminates during the runtime.Any help???

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void removeSpaces(string url){

int len=url.length();
int i,count=0;
while(i<=len){
if(url[i]==' ')
count++;
i++;
}
int length2=len+(count*2);
string newarr[length2];
for(int j=len-1;j>=0;j--){
if(url[j]==' ')
{
  newarr[length2-1]='0';
  newarr[length2-2]='2';
  newarr[length2-3]='%';
  length2=length2-3;
}
else
{
  newarr[length2-1]=url[j];
  length2=length2-1;
}
}
cout<<"\nThe number of spaces in the url is:"<<count;
cout<<"\nThe replaced url is:"<<newarr;

}

int main(){

string url="http://www.ya h o o.com/";
removeSpaces(url);
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a string _array_?

Comment: Is this homework? It should have the `homework` tag.

Comment: As in, you had to figure out everything wrong with it or you wrote it?

Comment: i wrote it and i tried compiling it and iam getting some weird errors during runtime.

Comment: do indentation. It would be easier to help you

Answer (score 6):

This is called an "off by one" error.

```
while(i<=len){
    if(url[i]==' ')
```

I'd also look at `std::string::find()` and `std::string::replace()` rather than what you're doing.

**EDIT:** Since the poster has said this isn't homework:

```
for (size_t pos = myString.find(' '); 
     pos != string::npos; 
     pos = myString.find(' ', pos))
{
    myString.replace(pos, 1, "%20");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i is not initialized to 0 - this is the danger if using ',' instead of putting each variable on its own line.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you're using `string` and not `char *`, why not use the `string` methods? This is essentially a translation of what you're trying to do (without even using `::find` or `::replace`):

```
void removeSpaces(string url)
{
    string newUrl;
    int count = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < url.length(); ++j)
    {
        if (url.at(j) == ' ')
        {
            newUrl.append("%20");
            ++count;
        }
        else
            newUrl.append(url.at(j));
    }

    cout << "\nThe number of spaces in the url is:" << count;
    cout << "\nThe replaced url is:"<< newUrl;
}
```

**Edit**: I see that @Bryan has given the version with `::find` and `::replace`.

Comment: Yeah, for efficiency I should have run the find() only from the last pos ... but I figured that should at least point him in the right direction. And we all know that premature optimization is bad :-D

Answer (score 2):

```
string newarr[length2];
```

should be:

```
string newarr;
```

or

```
char newarr[length2];
```

or the more proper way:

```
char *newarr = new char[length2];
... // code.
delete[] newarr;
```

Comment: The last way is the least proper way as it is not exception safe. Use a vector rather than dynamically allocating an array of characters.

Comment: @Martin York: Well, the variable length char array isn't even standard C++, so I'd say that's pretty improper.

Answer (score 1):

```
string replaceinString(std::string str, std::string tofind, std::string toreplace)
{
        size_t position = 0;
        for ( position = str.find(tofind); position != std::string::npos; position = str.find(tofind,position) )
        {
                str.replace(position ,1, toreplace);
        }
        return(str);
}
```

use it:

```
string replace = replaceinString(thisstring, " ", "%20");
string replace2 = replaceinString(thisstring, " ", "-");
string replace3 = replaceinString(thisstring, " ", "+");
```